# move_uploaded_file not working properly

Tags: php, sql, html

i would like to ask if someone knows what went wrong with my program.

you see, after i upload a file, the uploaded file is moved to the created folder document, the the other information like, uploadname and employee id that is supposed to be inserted in the database did not insert it. **the file was copied to the document but info did not insert.** i hope someone could help me. no errors where found in my code
 ****CASE CLOSED, but thanks for the help***

Answer (score 1):

First: You have only written insert query, you don't actually call mysql_query($insert_query);

Second: Are you sure all those inputs are valid? Try putting $company_id in single quotes too.

Also is there any error or warning message showing up?

**NOTE:** Remember to escape and validate your input! Look through this page: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You should call mysql_query($insert_query) after you assign value to $insert_query. So simply put it after the part you copied here.

Comment: there isnt no error found, and the file is almost working properly, its just that the other information in the file was not inserted to the database, although the file was moved to the specific folder

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following line at the end of the code.

```
mysql_query ($insert_query, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
```

It will try to insert the record otherwise will show the error in the page, so you can debug to identify the issue and fix easily.

Comment: isnt this what your saying?if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection)) {